# getActivity() becomes null in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following function inside a fragment

```
private Boolean checkIfDayChanged() {
    SharedPreferences getSharedData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long savedLong = getSharedData.getLong("currentDate", 1);
    return !DateUtils.isToday(savedLong);
}
```

This function is called initially in the onCreateView method (The activity returned by getActiity() is MainActivity). The fragment then loads another activity. When I return from the new activity to the fragment, the checkIfDayChanged() function is called again but the app crashes because now getActivity() returns null.

I have tried setting

```
private FragmentActivity activity;
```

for the fragment's class and using that instead of getActivity() but even then, I keep getting null and the app crashes.

How can I get a reference to the activity without it becoming null after returning from another activity?

Comment: `requireActivity` doesn't work?

Comment: If I use requireActivity I get an error saying that the fragment is not attached to an activity.

Comment: not sure if this will work or not.. try to set `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreateView` and see

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. Still says fragment is not attached to activity.

Comment: probably you want to `transaction.addToBackStack()`